# Script running with cron not reading from redirected stdin

Tags: bash, cron, stdout, stdin

I have a bash script with the following command

```
command1 < input.txt > output.txt
```

When I run it, the output.txt file is created and filled with almost 5mb of data. The problem is that when its it's run by cron it doesn't work. It creates the file output.txt but it's empty. I believe that what's happening is that it's not reading the input from input.txt so command1 exits right away, creating the output file but don't printing anything.

Anyone knows what is happening and how can it be fixed?

**EDIT:** After trying a lot of options it appears that the problem is that the cron is configured to redirect stdin, so no matter if I redirect stdin or if I pipe processes, nothing is able to read anything from stdin. ¿Any solution?

Comment: You can always create an standalone script what will contain the `command1 < input.txt > output.txt`, and run this new script from the `cron`. You can easily debug it...

Comment: Failures in running the `cron` would send a mail. Check your maillog.

Also when `cron` runs it runs with a different environment. So consider providing absolute file paths for `input.txt` and `output.txt`

Comment: I know cron is supposed to send a mail but in the environment I'm working it doesn't send it. Also I am using absolute file paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

login as superuser and invoke your command with 'env'.

```
env -i  command1 < input.txt > output.txt
```

With this you run the command (nearly) in the condition cron has.
You then will get error messages decribing your problem.